# Catch any error in tkinter and show as error else as succes message

Tags: python, pandas, tkinter, exception

How to chatch any error of this code and show it as error message, else as succes message.
This is my main code in my tkinter program, so what i want to do is cathcing all error that may occur in this main code. can u guys help me

```
def mainProcess():
 
    df1 = pd.read_excel(fileA)  # FILE TRANSAKSI BULANAN
    df2 = pd.read_excel(fileB)  # FILE ADMIN TRANSAKSI
    df3 = pd.read_excel(fileC)  # FILE AKHIR / INPUT

    # MENDAPAT NILAI PROPOSE

    df1.rename(columns={'agent_id':'AGENT_ID'}, inplace=True)
    df1.rename(columns={'description':'Nama Produk'}, inplace=True)

    df4 = pd.merge(df1, df2[['Nama Produk', 'Nilai Propose']], on='Nama Produk', how='left')


    # MENGUBAH MENJADI FIX INPUT AGENT

    df4 = df4.groupby(by="AGENT_ID").sum()[["Nilai Propose"]]
    df4["Korgen_40%"] = (df4["Nilai Propose"]) * 0.4
    df4["Agent_60%"] = (df4["Nilai Propose"]) * 0.6
    df4["Korlap_10%"] = (df4["Agent_60%"]) * 0.1
    df4["Agent_Recieved"] = (df4["Agent_60%"]) - (df4["Korlap_10%"])
    df4["Fix_Input_Agent"] = np.floor(df4["Agent_Recieved"])
    df4.reset_index(inplace=True)

    # MENGINPUT KE FILE INPUT 

    df5 = pd.merge(df3, df4[['AGENT_ID','Fix_Input_Agent']], on='AGENT_ID', how='left')
    df6 = df5['Fix_Input_Agent'].fillna(value = 0)

    df3["TRANSFER_VALUE"] = df6

    NamaFile1 = alterName1.get()  
    NamaFile2 = alterName2.get()  

    if NamaFile1 == '' or NamaFile2 == '':
        m_box.showerror('Caution', 'Nama File Tidak Boleh Kosong')

    a = alterName1.get()
    b = alterName2.get()

    df4.to_excel(a + ".xlsx",index=False)
    df3.to_excel(b + ".xlsx",index=False)
```

Comment: An error where?  Python will already present you with an error and a traceback should any error occur.  And, by the way, if `alterName1` or `alterName2` are empty, you present an error, but you keep on processing anyway.

Comment: i mean the error that could happen like, the columns are not matching if the user choose the wrong file so the program couldnt procces. so the user can notice with the message. and can u help me with the alterName too:) @TimRoberts

Comment: I don't know what "choose the wrong file" means for you.  You're fetching `alterName1` and `alterName2` twice, which is silly.  Just use `NamaFile1` and `NamaFile2` instead of `a` and `b`.  And I assume you want `return False` or something like it after your `showerror` call.  Only YOU know how you want to handle errors.

Comment: thank you so much TIm @TimRoberts, im sorry to make u confuse :) im so new to this python thingy. Gonna learn more about exception handling

Comment: OK, but let me point out that "exception handling" and "error handling' are not necessarily the same thing.  If there are conditions you can check BEFORE trying an operation, that's not going to involve exceptions.